# Search then replace as distinct steps in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace

I have some code that searches through text for match, then when it finds a match, performs a non-trivial transformation on the matched text, which I then want to replace with the result of this transformation. For example (ignoring [Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1270789) issues):

```
var text = "foo bar <sum>(10+33)/pi</sum> baz";
var matches = text.match(/<sum>[\s\S]+?<\/sum>/g);
matches.forEach(element => {
    var result = evaluateSum(element);
    // Now somehow replace element with result
});
```

I could cobble together a hack with [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), but there must be a neat way of doing this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback to `replace()` to calculate an arbitrary replacement.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `forEach()`, I would use a `reduce()` and reduce down the string.

```js
const evaluateSum = () => 100;

var text = "foo bar <sum>(10+33)/pi</sum> baz";
var matches = text.match(/<sum>[\s\S]+?<\/sum>/g);
const replacedText = matches.reduce((result, element) =>
  result.replace(element, evaluateSum(element)), text);
  
console.log(replacedText);
```

`reduce()` will loop through each element in an array, do something, return that something, and keep going until it's done that something for each element in the array.

It's a handy way to crunch down anything with an array to a single value.